# Are links from PDFs nofollowed by default?

Tags: seo, pdf

I have some PDFs on my site and those PDFs have links to my HTML pages. It looks like all the links from the PDFs to HTML pages are nofollowed. My assumption is that all links from PDFs are nofollowed ones by default? Is that really the case? Thanks

Comment: Have you checked that the content of those PDFs has been indexed? I do mean the content, not just the files.

Comment: How are you checking that the links look nofollowed?